# replace with n/a if n/a in column next to it

Tags: r, missing-data

For R:
I want for my second column to be n/a in any cell that has n/a in the column to the left. For example, my data look like this...

```
outcome <- c(1,2,NA,1,NA,3,1,2,3)
outcome2 <- c(0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,0) 
    
Data<- data.frame(outcome=outcome,outcome2=outcome2)
Data
```

but I would like to transform the outcome2 variable to this...

```
outcome <- c(1,2,NA,1,NA,3,1,2,3)
outcome2 <- c(0,1,NA,0,NA,1,1,1,0) 

Data<- data.frame(outcome=outcome,outcome2=outcome2)
Data
```

Comment: Make sure to tag your question with the programming language you're using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `replace` + `is.na`

```
within(Data,outcome2 <- replace(outcome2,is.na(outcome),NA))
```

or

```
within(Data,outcome2 <- 0**outcome + outcome2)
```

which gives

```
  outcome outcome2
1       1        0
2       2        1
3      NA       NA
4       1        0
5      NA       NA
6       3        1
7       1        1
8       2        1
9       3        0
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose:

```
Data$outcome2 <- ifelse(is.na(Data$outcome), NA, Data$outcome2)
```